# About running several simple regression at once

Tags: r

Want to run four linear models at once

I have a data containing four dependent and 4 independent variables. I have created a list of dependent variables and also created a list of independent variables. I want to run 4 linear models at once like

```
lm(y1~x1)
lm(y2~x2)
lm(y3~x3)
lm(y4~x4)
```

Although i can do it one by one but i want to run at once. Plz help

Comment: Checkout `parallel::mcmapply`

Comment: By "at once" do you mean at the same time (in parallel), or just a way of automating so that one runs after another?

Comment: Sir I want all intercepts at once

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

First, input some data into frames.

```
x.values<-data.frame(
             x_1 = rnorm(10),
             x_2 = rnorm(10),
             x_3 = rnorm(10)
             )

y.values<-data.frame(y_1 = rnorm(10),
                 y_2 = rnorm(10),
                 y_3 = rnorm(10)
)
```

Then, make the formula with regular expression

```
lmformulas <- list(as.formula(paste(grep("y_[1]", names(y.values), value = TRUE), paste(grep("x_[1]", names(x.values), value = TRUE), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")),
               as.formula(paste(grep("y_[2]", names(y.values), value = TRUE), paste(grep("x_[2]", names(x.values), value = TRUE), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")),
               as.formula(paste(grep("y_[3]", names(y.values), value = TRUE), paste(grep("x_[3]", names(x.values), value = TRUE), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))
               )
```

[[1]]
y_1 ~ x_1

[[2]]
y_2 ~ x_2

[[3]]
y_3 ~ x_3`

Finnaly, you can get the result you want 'at once'

```
lm_result <- lapply(lmformulas, function(x) {
lm(x, data = cbind(y.values,x.values))
}
)
```

[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = cbind(y.values, x.values))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x_1
    -0.6081       0.1041

[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = cbind(y.values, x.values))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x_2
  -0.452157    -0.001287

[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = cbind(y.values, x.values))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          x_3
    -0.1945      -0.1830